# How can one define an infix operator with an arbitrary unicode character?

Tags: front-end, syntax, syntax-highlighting, custom-notation

You can setup "UsefulFunction[a, b]" to use custom infix notation "a ↔ b" as follows:

```
Needs["Notation`"];
AddInputAlias["4" -> ParsedBoxWrapper["↔"]];
InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper["↔"], FlatJoin];
```

[image]

But using a unicode character that does not have a mathematica definition (e.g. "\[name]") such as ":27d7" gives you an error:

[image]

Now the syntax highlighting is broken, and that is really my question: *how can you tell mathematica to correctly syntax highlight new unicode infix operators?*

(Note: the messages can by avoided by adding internal information on the character as follows:

```
Notation`Private`internalCharacterInformation["⋗"] = {"0x2295", "Infix", "450", "None", "3", "3", "MyOp"}; InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper["⋗"], FlatJoin]
```

**Edit:**

I'm now pretty sure that the answer will involve editing /Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/UnicodeCharacters.tr

and adding something like

```
0x22D7      \[FlatJoin]     ($fj$   $&FlatJoin;$   $\oplus$)      Infix       320     None        4       4
```

and then using the Notations package...

Comment: Pardon me, but how should the operator be highlighted?  Does your `internalCharacterInformation` method fix highlighting to your satisfaction?

Comment: It should be highlighted just like the \\[LeftRightArrow] in the first output image: red when used improperly, and black otherwise. Also, no the Notation`Private`internalCharacterInformation trick only stops InfixNotation from complaining.

Comment: See my answer below.  I shall admit I've never used this kind of modification myself and I don't know what kinds of problems may result.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can get the syntax highlighting that you desire by modifying your `UnicodeCharacters.tr` file (path given by `` System`Dump`unicodeCharactersTR ``), though I don't know how advisable this practice is.

For example, adding:

```
0x20B0      \[PennyOp]      ($penny$)    Infix       155     None        5       5
```

I can use <kbd>Esc</kbd>`penny`<kbd>Esc</kbd> to enter:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

I am not aware of documentation of the format of this file but as best I can tell the columns are:

1. the Unicode address in hex
2. the FullForm String representation
3. input aliases separated by tabs
4. the use or type of the symbol
5. parsing precedence
6. `Left`, `Right` or `None` -- I assume an [associativity](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Infix.html#7253) control
7. left whitespace padding to place around the character (in StandardForm)
8. right whitespace padding

---

#### Completing the operator

Additional code is required to turn such a character into a valid operator.  Please see these additional questions for the rest of the story:

- [How is + as an infix operator associated with Plus?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31375/121)
- [How to define a number of infix operators with predefined relative precedences](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89762/121)

Comment: But what exactly do these columns mean?

Comment: @Mike I'm still figuring that out.  I believe: the first column is the Unicode address in hex; the second is the FullForm string representation; the third is any input aliases separated by tabs; the fourth is the use or type of the symbol; the fifth is precedence; the sixth is `Left`, `Right` or `None` -- I assume a binding control; the last two columns are left and right whitespace padding to place around the character (in StandardForm).

Comment: You think that column 6 lists the same "grouping (associativity) specifications" as written under **More information** of e.g. [`Infix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Infix.html)?

Comment: @István yes I believe so but I haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of using the `Notation` package, you can achieve the translation by doing the following:

```
MakeExpression[RowBox[{x_, "⟗", y_}], StandardForm] := 
 MakeExpression[
  RowBox[{"FlatJoin", "[", x, ",", y, "]"}], 
  StandardForm
 ]
```

This takes care of the input translation. 
Now it's possible to enter expressions like

```
1 ⟗ (3 + 4 ⟗ 2)
```

and have Mathematica understand that it means

```
FlatJoin[1, 3 + FlatJoin[4, 2]]
```

If you want `FlatJoin` to remain undefined and just have the symbolic display, you may also want to define an output format:

```
FlatJoin /: MakeBoxes[FlatJoin[x_, y_], StandardForm] := 
 RowBox[{"(", MakeBoxes[x, StandardForm], "⟗", 
   MakeBoxes[y, StandardForm], ")"}]
```

But as soon as you provide a definition for `FlatJoin`, this output format won't really be needed.

**Edit**

The above gets rid of the error messages reported in the question. To get syntax highlighting for incomplete expressions, Mathematica needs to know that it's dealing with a binary operator. The easiest way to do that is of course to make use of one of the operators that is already pre-defined, see the list in [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html); you can select any operator that has no built-in meaning, see [this doc page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OperatorsWithoutBuiltInMeanings.html).

The reason why syntax highlighting doesn't work for general (unicode or other) atomic characters in the abbreviated infix notation `1 ⟗ 2` is that they are interpreted as multiplications by a variable of that name.

Comment: Exactly, so how can gone introduce a new character and tell Mathematica that it is supposed to be a binary operator?

Answer (score 4):

You can fix the syntax coloring by using a [`TagBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagBox) to customize [`AutoStyleOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AutoStyleOptions) (the syntax colorer thinks the operator is an undefined symbol):

```
AddInputAlias["4" -> ParsedBoxWrapper @ TagBox[
    "⟗",
    FlatJoin,
    BaseStyle->{AutoStyleOptions->{System`UndefinedSymbolStyle->{FontColor->GrayLevel[0]}}},
    SyntaxForm->"↔"
    ]
]

InfixNotation[
    ParsedBoxWrapper @ TagBox[
        "⟗",
        FlatJoin,
        BaseStyle->{AutoStyleOptions->{System`UndefinedSymbolStyle->{FontColor->GrayLevel[0]}}},
        SyntaxForm->"↔"
    ],
    FlatJoin
]
```

Note that this also fixes the error messages you get when defining the notation. Here is a screen shot showing that the operator turns black as desired:

[image]