# Left-associative Apply

Tags: function-construction

Often I want a version of `@` that is left-associative (might not be using that term correctly).

What I mean is I'd like some operator `l@` such that:

```
a l@ b l@ c === a[b][c]
```

Standard `@` gives us:

```
a @ b @ c === a[b[c]]
```

Is there such an operator I've overlooked? (I don't want to use brackets on brackets on brackets)

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11908/403

Comment: Also: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6355/403

Comment: Interesting question, can it be that the documentation is wrong for [`Infix`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Infix.html)? According to documentation something like `Infix[ f[a,b,c], "~", 490, Left ]` is supposed to word but does not. The same syntax should also work for `Prefix`.

Comment: Being pedantic, the title of the question isn't strictly correct: `Apply` is `@@`, not `@`. The operators `@` and `//` are both called ["function application"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FunctionCompositionAndOperatorForms.html) in the Docs. So more correct title would be "Function application with left-associative grouping".

Answer (score 14):

I am not aware of a built-in operator that will call a function with individual sub-value arguments (i.e. curried arguments).

The function [Curry](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Curry.html) has a promising-sounding name, but it lifts a function that takes uncurried arguments into one that takes curried arguments -- sort of the opposite of what we want here.

We could define our own by pressing one of the [operators without built-in meanings](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorsWithoutBuiltInMeanings.html) into service.  Let's use [CirclePlus](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CirclePlus.html) (`⊕`) in one of the following ways:

```
CirclePlus[f_, r___] := Fold[Construct, f, {r}]
```

or prior to version 11.3:

```
CirclePlus[f_, r___] := Fold[#[#2]&, f, {r}]
```

or using the [now undocumented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5687109/211232) function [HeadCompose](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v1/contents/list215.pdf):

```
CirclePlus = HeadCompose;
```

With any of these, we can then write:

```
f⊕a

(* f[a] *)

f⊕a⊕b

(* f[a][b] *)

f⊕a⊕b⊕c

(* f[a][b][c] *)

f⊕a⊕b⊕c⊕d

(* f[a][b][c][d] *)
```

Comment: As I noted in a comment to Carl Woll the issue is that I can't trust these operator forms to not have rules attached to them by someone else. I don't like to play with ``"System`"`` level symbols since I can't scope them without potentially breaking someone else's code. What I had to do, inefficient though it is, was to simply attach a `DownValue` to my primary object that took a pattern like `a["method"[]@["property"]]` and rewrite it as `a["method[]]@"property"`. As long as I use strings for method and property names there's no danger with premature evaluation here.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I'm inclined to agree with you about overloading the operator forms.  It is a powerful tool for _project_ work...  but use in _library code_ is downright dangerous.

Answer (score 12):

Another alternative is to use a built-in operator form that has left-associative grouping. A couple examples:

```
CircleMinus[a_, b_] := a[b]
a ⊖ b ⊖ c
```

> a[b][c]

```
LeftTee[a_, b_] := a[b]
a ⊣ b ⊣ c
```

> a[b][c]

Comment: Thank you! I have been looking for a left-associative operator for a long time! I suppose that in order to fully emulate parsing behavior of `@`, it would be a good idea to add `HoldAllComplete` as well. Compare with and without `HoldAllComplete`: `a[b] = HoldComplete; c = 1; a\[CircleMinus]b\[CircleMinus]c`

Comment: I'm always uncomfortable using these built-in operators because I don't want to take one out of commission for other people... On the other hand I can't just use my own symbol and attach a `MakeBoxes` rule to it because this needs to work inside a package -_- It's just too dangerous, though, to use one of these ``"System`"`` level ones since there's no way to scope its effect.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Would having an input alias work for you? Or does it have to be InputForm only because it's in a package?

Comment: It would be used in a package unfortunately. Realistically no one else will ever use it, probably, but I’d like to adhere to good development practices despite that.