# How to define custom operators

Tags: algebra

I am currently running *Mathematica* 8 and I would like to know how to define custom operators.

Let's say I define an operator called $\times$ where:

$$a\times b = a+a\cdot b+b$$

I also want to know if it is commutative, associative, its inverse, identity and whether it is closed for Z. How would I do that in *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 7):

For the first part of your question please see a very recent Q&A:

["How is + as an infix operator associated with Plus?"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31377/187)

There you will find everything about defining operators yourself. For the second part, lets use your definition and bind it to [`CircleTimes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CircleTimes.html).

```
CircleTimes[a_, b_] := a + a*b + b;
```

Now you can verify some of your assumptions. I use images instead of code-blocks, so that you see the rendered output. The operator can be inserted with the combination <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>. Verify commutativity:

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

associativity

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Inverse element which does not necessarily exist in $\mathbb{Z}$

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

and the identity can be calculated likewise. I don't know whether you can show with *Mathematica* that this operator is closed in $\mathbb{Z}$, but you could easily make this clear, since you only use + and * which is closed in $\mathbb{Z}$.

I hope this gives you some point to start.