# Define inverse for the custom operator

Tags: matrix, algebraic-manipulation

I want to define simple matrix algebra (inspired by the following posts:
[Block Matrix Algebra with Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37808/block-matrix-algebra-with-mathematica)
;
[How to define custom operators](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31554/how-to-define-custom-operators)
).

I assume the funtion `MatrixMult[A_,B_]` to be the matrix product. I surely can define some properties of this function, like linearity, associativity etc. (see referenced posts).
Now I want to solve simple matrix equation

```
Solve[MatrixMult[A, X]==B,X]
```

Obviously, the answer is

```
{{X -> InverseFunction[MatrixMult, 2, 2][A, B]}}
```

Now the question is how can I explicitly define that the inverse of my function is the following:

```
InverseFunction[MatrixMult, 2, 2][A_, B_] := MatrixMult[Inverse[A], B]
```

(the last line results in *"Tag InverseFunction is Protected"* error)

Comment: Either unprotect the symbol or change the name of your predicate. Also look up `What are the most common pitfalls ...` thread and see the difference between `=` and `:=` when defining predicates.

Comment: I get the idea about `Unprotect`, but still couldn't get it work. After I define the inverse function (with `SetDelayed`)  the `Solve` function returns `{}`. What do you mean by "change the name of your predicate"?

Comment: Well, `InverseFunction` is a built-in predicate, so you can't just use it overwrite it.

Comment: Both `Solve` and `InverseFunction` are meant to be used with scalars only.  What you are asking for would not be useful in this specific situation.  For symbolic matrix algebra, google for the NCAlgebra package.

Comment: @Szabolcs I am talking about simple abstract algebraic manipulations, so both `Solve` and `InverseFunction` used with scalars only. (I will not try to substitute any actual matrices into `A, B` etc.). (I am aware of NCAlgebra package)

Comment: Redefining built-ins is usually not a good idea, as it might break random and unexpected things.  (This is a good example: `Solve` won't even return the `InverseFunction` any more.)  What you could do instead is use a replacement rule that is not tied to `InverseFunction` and apply it manually, i.e. `result /. InverseFunction[MatrixMult, 2, 2][A_, B_] :> MatrixMult[Inverse[A], B]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can use [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues) to control the behavior of your `MatrixMult` function. We also need to teach `MatrixMult` how to handle [`Inverse`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inverse) as well:

```
MatrixMult[a_, MatrixMult[Inverse[a_], b_]] := b

MatrixMult /: InverseFunction[MatrixMult, 2, 2] = MatrixMult[Inverse[#1], #2]&
```

Notice that I don't try to give a definition for `InverseFunction[MatrixMult, 2, 2][a_, b_]` because then `MatrixMult` is buried to deep for [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues) to work. Now, let's try using [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve):

```
Solve[MatrixMult[A, X] == B, X]
```

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.
>
> {{X -> MatrixMult[Inverse[A], B]}}

One could avoid the message by explicitly telling [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) that you want to use inverse functions:

```
Solve[MatrixMult[A, X] == B, X, InverseFunctions->True]
```

> {{X -> MatrixMult[Inverse[A], B]}}

**VerifySolutions**

The `MatrixMult` [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) above is needed because [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) tries to verify its solution. An alternative to giving `MatrixMult` the above [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) is to tell [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) not to verify its solution:

```
Clear[MatrixMult]
MatrixMult /: InverseFunction[MatrixMult, 2, 2] = MatrixMult[Inverse[#1], #2]&;

Solve[MatrixMult[A, X] == B, X, InverseFunctions->True, VerifySolutions->False]
```

> {{X -> MatrixMult[Inverse[A], B]}}