# Using user-defined inverse functions with Solve

Tags: equation-solving, inverse

I am trying to solve with:

```
ClearAll[myCeiling];
myCeiling /: InverseFunction[myCeiling[x_]] := myFloor[x];
```

using

```
Solve[a == myCeiling[b/7], b, InverseFunctions -> True]
(* => {{b -> 7*InverseFunction[myCeiling, 1, 1][a]}} *)
```

gets incorrect result (ignores the defined `InverseFunction`) and if I set

```
ClearAll[myCeiling];
myCeiling /: InverseFunction[myCeiling] := myFloor
```

the result is just empty list `{}`

How do I correctly define `InverseFunction` for my function to use with `Solve` and `InverseFunctions -> True`?

**Edit**

Setting `DownValue` also results in empty `List`:

```
ClearAll[myCeiling];
Unprotect[InverseFunction];
InverseFunction[myCeiling] := myFloor;
Solve[a == myCeiling[b/7], b, InverseFunctions -> True]
(* => {} *)
```

And since when I check the `DownValues` of `InverseFunction` they seem to be no different from any other definition

```
DownValues[InverseFunction][[1]]//FullForm
(* RuleDelayed[HoldPattern[InverseFunction[ArcCos]],Cos] *)
DownValues[InverseFunction][[29]]//FullForm
(* RuleDelayed[HoldPattern[InverseFunction[myCeiling]],myFloor] *)
```

I assume this might be some kind of bug in `Solve`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(This question is basically a duplicate of [Define inverse for the custom operator](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43277/45431), but I will customize that answer to your question.)*

The issue you are running into is that [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) automatically verifies solutions when [`InverseFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction) objects are involved. So, either use `VerifySolutions->False`:

```
Solve[a == myCeiling[b/7], b, InverseFunctions -> True, VerifySolutions->False]
```

> {{b -> 7 myFloor[a]}}

or teach `myCeiling` how to handle `myFloor` objects:

```
myCeiling[myFloor[x_]] := x

Solve[a == myCeiling[b/7], b, InverseFunctions -> True]
```

> {{b -> 7 myFloor[a]}}