# How to assign symbols to functions

Tags: core-language

Several functions work with symbols in MMA:
Take for example `Part`:

```
l1=l2=Range[4];
l1[[3]]
(*3*)
l2[[4]]
(*4*)
```

I want to make my own function work in the same way.

I can do some thing like this:

```
p[l_,x_]:=l[[x]]
p[l1,3]
(*3*)
p[l2,4]
(*4*)
```

Now I want to use a symbol for example assign `[[[]]]]` or `[*@]` (or any other symbol) to my `p` function so that I can do something like this:

```
l1[[[3]]]
(*3*)
l2[[[4]]]
(*4*)
```

or

```
l1[*@3]
(*3*)
l2[*@4]
(*4*)
```

Comment: What would you like your operator to do though, and what syntax do you have in mind for it? As a possible starting point, you might want to take a look at the list of existing [operators without built-in meanings](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorsWithoutBuiltInMeanings.html) and try to assign your operation to one of those.

Comment: I don't think you can define operator symbols yourself, but you can use undefined ones like `CirclePlus`.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries how to do that? I don't know even how to assigned any operator symbols to function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll give you a simple example of one operator without built-in meaning that I have re-purposed.

I recently found myself plotting functions or evaluating integrals on a square domain centered on the origin that could be represented by `Rectangle[{-a, -a}, {a, a}]`. Tired of typing in the `Rectangle` expression, I noticed that there is a `Square` expression and operator (esc+sq+esc, $\square$) that is defined but has no meaning, so I assigned it one as follows:

```
Clear[Square]
Square[x_ /; x > 0] := Rectangle[{-x, -x}, {x, x}]
```

I can now write expressions like the following:

```
ContourPlot[Cos[(x^2 - y^2)/3], {x, y} \[Element] \[Square](2 Pi), PlotPoints -> 50]
```

which will look like this in the notebook:

[image: ContourPlot expression]

[image: ContourPlot output]

... or like the following:

```
Integrate[Cos[(x^2 - y^2)/3], {x, y} \[Element] \[Square]3]
```

which will look like this:

[image: integral expression]

[image: integral output]

Answer (score 4):

This solution doesn't provide quite the flexibility that you've given as an example but may still be satisfactory:

Have a look at:
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorsWithoutBuiltInMeanings.html
and
[How to define custom operators](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31554/how-to-define-custom-operators)

That'll allow you to assign a function to an unused (or used) in-fix operator. Operator precedence may be important to consider if you do this (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html). I don't remember if you can / how to redefine operator preference to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

```
l1 = l2 = Range[4];
p[l_, x_] := l[[x]]
```

This is a example of `MakeExpression`. You might need to make a new expression like this.

```
MakeExpression[RowBox[{l_, "[", 
      RowBox[{"[", RowBox[{"[", x_, "]"}], "]"}], "]"}], StandardForm] := 
 MakeExpression[RowBox[{"p", "[",RowBox[{l, ",", x}], "]"}], StandardForm]

l1[[[3]]]
(*3*)
```

And other example.

```
MakeExpression[RowBox[{l_, "[", 
      RowBox[{"*", RowBox[{"@", x_}]}], "]"}], StandardForm] := 
 MakeExpression[RowBox[{"p", "[", RowBox[{l, ",", x}], "]"}], StandardForm]

l1[*@3]
(*3*)
```