# Define operator with special characters

Tags: function-construction, variable-definitions

I have looked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15605/how-to-define-a-differential-operator) which describes how to define operators. I was wondering whether there was a way to assign thes operators to special characters? *eg* Let $\odot:=(a+b)(ab),$ so `4\[CircleDot]3` would yield `84`? It is really a stylistic / display issue - of course the same could be achieved with `cd[a_,b_]:=(a+b) a b`, implemented with `cd[a,b]`.

Comment: Take a look at this question, see if my answer there might help you along: [How to assign symbols to functions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84464/27951)

Comment: @MarcoB I have taken a look at the link, but usure on syntax when it comes to applying it to the example above

Comment: I think Karsten took care of that below :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CircleDot[a_, b_] := (a + b) a b
```

Now

```
4⊙3
```

> ```
> 84
> ```

Comment: ha! I didn't think it would be that simple - I thought the operator would have to preceed the arguments - thank you! :)

Comment: @martin `4⊙3//FullForm` may shed some light on your confusion. Some operators are *infix*, meaning `⊙` is the same as `~CircleDot~` and we know, that `a~CircleDot~b` is the same as `CircleDot[a,b]`. But in fact, you could just as easily set like so: `a_⊙b_:=(a + b) a b`, MMA would interpret this just like the full form that Karsten showed in this answer.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP ah, I see - much like `~Join~`

Comment: @martin precisely. When in doubt, always check the `FullForm` :)