# Define an operator for FileNameJoin

Tags: operators

When I join file names, it's inconvenient to use FileNameJoin. The workaround is to use <> instead, however <> is not exactly like FileNameJoin.

I tried to define an operator . It just doesn't work. If I can define it, I can use it to construct file name like this, "dir1"  "dir2" <> "file".

In:

```
x_ < /> y_ := FileNameJoin[{x, y}]
```

Out:

> Syntax::sntxf: "x_<" cannot be followed by "/>y_".

This is what I do, however I got an error. How can I fix it?

Comment: it's possible to define new operators using the ``Notations` `` package (see other answers for details). But in your case maybe you just want an alias, say `FNJ` and then you can use `x~FNJ~y`?The notations all work from box forms, which can cause issues if you embed them in a package.

Comment: @MB1965, I prefer </>, because it's like <>, but it can add /(path separator) automatically. Thanks, I will try it with Notations`.

Comment: Perhaps you could choose an operator without built-in meanings from the tutorial [Operators without Built-in Meanings](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorsWithoutBuiltInMeanings.html)

Comment: E.g., `TildeTilde = FileNameJoin@*List`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XT6Jg.png

Comment: Right, it's handy.

Comment: Possibly of interest: [(27081)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27081/121), [(31375)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31375/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you were to choose `TildeTilde` as Michael E2 suggests. Then you don't need the Symbol Package since `≈` has interpretation as an operator already built-in.

```
TildeTilde[names___] := FileNameJoin[{names}]
```

Then

```
TildeTilde[$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "my_file.dat"]
```

gives me

> `"/Users/oldmg/Desktop/my_file.dat"`

and more to the point,

```
$HomeDirectory ≈ "Desktop" ≈ "my_file.dat"
```

> `"/Users/oldmg/Desktop/my_file.dat"`

There is an input alias for `≈`. You can type <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to get `≈`. Input aliases seem be defined for most (maybe all?) of the operators with no built-in meaning.

Comment: No need to add an alias for `\[TildeTilde]`, it already works.

Comment: @CarlWoll. +1 I should have checked the docs. It looks like all the unassigned operator symbols have input aliases. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Note that you can use `WolframLanguageData` (or `EntityValue`) to find out what the keyboard shortcuts are, e.g., `WolframLanguageData["TildeTilde", "KeyboardShortcuts"]`

Comment: @CarlWoll. That seems like more trouble than consulting the Documentation Center.

Comment: However, if you wanted to verify that all operators in a list have an input alias, it would be a lot easier to use `WolframLanguageData` than the Documentation Center.

Answer (score 3):

I favor the method m_goldberg shows but an alternative is Rojo's `SubscriptBox` method from [Is it possible to define custom compound assignment operators like ⊕= similar to built-ins +=, *= etc?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27081/121#39703)

```
MakeExpression[
  RowBox[arg : {_, PatternSequence[SubscriptBox["<>", "/"], _] ..}], 
  StandardForm
] := 
  MakeExpression @ RowBox[{"FileNameJoin", "[", "{", ##, "}", "]"}] & @@ 
    Riffle[arg[[;; ;; 2]], ","]
```

Now:

[image]

To enter this operator in Windows type <kbd><</kbd>  <kbd>></kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>) <kbd>/</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd>

Comment: How to type <>/ ? I tried to use the result of SubscriptBox["<>", "/"] // InputForm, however it doesn't work.

Comment: @UnchartedWorks I added the exact key presses needed in Windows.