# How to make a binary function associative? (Or define an n-ary function?)

Tags: operators

Suppose I have a simple function that I assign to an operator

```
f[a_, b_] := a + b
CirclePlus = f
```

Then I want to write

```
1 (+) 2 (+) 3
```

But it doesn't work, because it's trying to evaluate `f[1,2,3]`.

So how does one instruct Mathematica that it should instead evaluate `f[f[1,2],3]`, or alternatively how does one work with infix operators? I'd be okay if I had to write my as `f[a_List]` instead, and then took care of things myself ...

-- Edit:

As the answer was deleted, note that making the function `Flat` is not the answer, here, as far as I can see.

-- Edit:

Here is an exact copy of the MMA file to reproduce this problem

```
In[13]:= f[a_,b_]:=a+b;
f[a_,b_,c_]:=f[f[a,b],c]
CirclePlus=f;
1\[CirclePlus]2\[CirclePlus]5\[CirclePlus]6
Out[16]= f[1,2,5,6]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can tell it by making a definition what it should do if you have more then 2 arguments:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[a_, b_, c__] := f[f[a, b], c];
CirclePlus = f
```

Then you get

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

And of course you have to add the definition of `f` when it is called as binary function. So for instance, and only for the purpose of showing what happens:

```
f[a_, b_] := Row[{"(", a, "\[CirclePlus]", b, ")"}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is how it looks when you use more than 3 terms. Note that the pattern is recursively applied until there are only 2 arguments in each call:

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This only works if I have only three terms; it doesn't make it generally associative (i.e. it doesn't work if there are 4 terms.)

Comment: @NoonSilk And you say this because you have tried it?

Comment: Yes, I did try it. Did you?

Comment: So you don't get the same result that I get for the 5 arguments in my last example?

Comment: No.

This is what I have:

In[13]:= f[a_,b_]:=a+b;
f[a_,b_,c_]:=f[f[a,b],c]
CirclePlus=f;
1\[CirclePlus]2\[CirclePlus]5\[CirclePlus]6
Out[16]= f[1,2,5,6]

Comment: I can't format the code properly in the comment so I've added it as an edit to the original post.

Comment: There is a big difference between one underscore `a_` which is a `Blank[]` and two underscores `a__` which is a `BlackSequence[]`. Please **copy** my example and try it. Btw, if you add the definition `a+b` you wont see anything, because it is instantly evaluated to a number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22173/discussion-between-halirutan-and-noon-silk).

Comment: I did not see the second underscore there; indeed -- seeing it instantly evaluate is what I want to see!

With the underscore this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

halirutan demonstrated how to adapt your function `f` to handle multiple arguments but that changes the game: `f` is no longer a binary function.

The other aspect of this problem is that the [`CirclePlus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CirclePlus.html) operator itself is not binary; rather it accepts a series of arguments as illustrated in the question.  [`CircleMinus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CircleMinus.html) *is* a binary operator, and with it your code works as written:

```
f[a_, b_] := a + b
CircleMinus = f;

q ⊖ r ⊖ s ⊖ t
```

> ```
> q + r + s + t
> ```

This of course would be a confusing choice of operator for this function but it serves as illustration.  An additional property that must be considered is left versus right association.  `CircleMinus` is left-associative:

```
CircleMinus = foo;

q ⊖ r ⊖ s ⊖ t
```

> ```
> foo[foo[foo[q, r], s], t]
> ```

[`Therefore`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Therefore.html) is right-associative:

```
Therefore = foo;

q ∴ r ∴ s ∴ t
```

> ```
> foo[q, foo[r, foo[s, t]]]
> ```

Care should be exercised when choosing an [operator](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Operators.html) for your function!

Comment: Well, in my case I'm actually performing a matrix direct sum, so I wanted the direct sum symbol. And that operation is associative. So how do I make CirclePlus be associative in the way I want?

Comment: @NoonSilk Theoretically you could edit the entry for CirclePlus in `UnicodeCharacters.tr` following the format described here [(6363)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6363/121) but I strongly recommend against it as your code will only work on a similarly modified system.  I recommend that you choose a different existing operator, or possibly create a new one as also described in the post  linked above.

Comment: Yeah, I won't be editing that file. It seems crazy that I can't make this operator associative!

Comment: @NoonSilk I believe it is a design choice, not necessarily one that I defend, but at least one I think I understand.  The operator associativity is a low-level property that affects parsing itself.  User definitions are applied *after* parsing.  Therefore to affect this one must edit low-level properties, i.e. `UnicodeCharacters.tr`.  *Mathematica* simply isn't designed to allow low-level modification of the syntax itself; even resource files such as `UnicodeCharacters.tr` are only limited exceptions to this.  One would have to write his own parser to define a truly custom language syntax.