# How to map an inequality to a list?

Tags: map

```
vars = Table[Subscript[a, j], {j, 5}]
```

We can do the total

```
Total[vars]
```

and produce

```
Times@@vars
```

What's the most efficient way to get this

> {Subscript[a, 1]<=Subscript[a, 2]<=Subscript[a, 3]<=Subscript[a, 4]<=Subscript[a, 5]}

I can't seem to find a proper way to map this.

Comment: It's just `LessEqual @@ vars` :-)

Answer (score 5):

Rather than considering this question "too simple" and closing it I tried to think of a way to make it or its answer of wider interest.  It seems to me that for this question to have been asked it must not be clear that there is equivalence between `<=` and `LessEqual`, and/or that `LessEqual` is not a binary function but can receive many arguments.

One can see with [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) that operators such as `<=` are represented by a common Head such as `LessEqual`.  Some other examples:

```
expr = {
  a < b < c,
  a <= b <= c,
  a > b > c,
  a >= b >= c,
  a == b == c,
  a != b != c,
  a && b && c,
  a | b | c,
  a.b.c
};

FullForm /@ expr // Column
```

> ```
> Less[a, b, c]
> LessEqual[a, b, c]
> Greater[a, b, c]
> GreaterEqual[a, b, c]
> Equal[a, b, c]
> Unequal[a, b, c]
> And[a, b, c]
> Alternatives[a, b, c]
> Dot[a, b, c]
> ```

Therefore these and other heads may be used to construct such expressions:

```
operators = {Less, LessEqual, Greater, GreaterEqual, Equal, Unequal, Dot, And, Or, Nand, 
   Nor, Xor, Alternatives, Equivalent, Proportional};

list = {a, b, c, d, e};

Table[
 op @@ list,
 {op, operators}
]
```

> ```
> {a < b < c < d < e, a <= b <= c <= d <= e, a > b > c > d > e, a >= b >= c >= d >= e, 
>  a == b == c == d == e, a != b != c != d != e, a.b.c.d.e, a && b && c && d && e, 
>  a || b || c || d || e, a ⊼ b ⊼ c ⊼ d ⊼ e, 
>  a ⊽ b ⊽ c ⊽ d ⊽ e, a ⊻ b ⊻ c ⊻ d ⊻ e, 
>  a | b | c | d | e, a ⧦ b ⧦ c ⧦ d ⧦ e, 
>  a ∝ b ∝ c ∝ d ∝ e}
> ```

Not included in the example are `SameQ` and `UnsameQ` only because those evaluate on symbolic arguments:

```
SameQ @@ list
UnsameQ @@ list
```

> ```
> False
> True
> ```

With holding to prevent that evaluation:

```
SameQ @@@ HoldForm @@ {list}
UnsameQ @@@ HoldForm @@ {list}
```

> ```
> a === b === c === d === e
> a =!= b =!= c =!= d =!= e
> ```

All of the operators shown above are of the kind that work with multiple arguments.  Not all operators are like this.  For other operators one may refer to the [Operator Precedence Table](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html).  Note that something like `Map` parses differently:

```
HoldForm @ FullForm[a /@ b /@ c /@ d /@ e]
```

> ```
> Map[a, Map[b, Map[c, Map[d, e]]]]
> ```

(I believe this is known as a right-associative operator.)  One therefore *cannot* construct an equivalent expression with `Apply`:

```
 Map @@ {a, b, c, d, e}
```

> Map::nonopt: Options expected (instead of e) beyond position 3 in Map[a,b,c,d,e]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules. >>
>
> ```
> Map[a, b, c, d, e]
> ```

---

Recommended reading:

- [How to make a binary function associative? (Or define an n-ary function?)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77913/how-to-make-a-binary-function-associative-or-define-an-n-ary-function/77925#77925)

Comment: Another possibility: `Inequality @@ Riffle[list, LessEqual]`. This allows for slightly more flexibility, e.g. `Inequality @@ Riffle[list, {LessEqual, Less}]`.

Comment: @Guess Would you care to discuss `Inequality` in a separate answer?  I had overlooked it and as I recall it is somewhat complex in its interaction with the other operators.

Comment: I was hoping you would :D, but I guess I can try writing a demo later…

Comment: @Guess OK, maybe if I have time.