# How to give a property to a list of functions?

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, operators

For example, I have defined a bunch of binary functions `Sum1`, `Sum2`, `Prod1`, `Prod2`, ... I want to make these functions associative, that is, the expression `Sum1[a,b,c]` will be evaluated as `Sum1[Sum1[a,b],c]`. I use the method [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77913/how-to-make-a-binary-function-associative-or-define-an-n-ary-function) to achieve it:

`Sum1[a_,b_,c__]:=Sum1[Sum1[a,b],c]`

Now I want to do this to all of these binary functions without repeating it line by line (because there are too many of them). Is there a way to do it? I tried to do the following

`Do[f[a_,b_,c__]:=f[f[a,b],c],{f,{Sum1,Sum2,Prod1,Prod2}}]`

But after this, when I evaluate `Sum1[a,b,c]`, it will return `f[f[a,b],c]`! In other words, the `f` after the `:=` is not substituted by the instances from the list `{Sum1,Sum2,Prod1,Prod2}`.

Comment: `Do[With[{f=f}, f[a_,b_,c__]:=f[f[a,b],c]],{f,{Sum1,Sum2,Prod1,Prod2}}]`

Comment: @I.M. That works, but generally I think that if you feel like you need to use `With[{f = f}, ...]` you really should be using a `Function` and some mapping construct instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
install[f_Symbol]:=(f[a_,b_,c__]:=f[f[a,b],c];);
Scan[install,{Sum1,Sum2,Prod1,Prod2}];
```

You may also want to have a look at `Flat` and `OneIdentity`, see [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Patterns.html#28368), but using them can be tricky.

Comment: I have looked at Flat, but I am always confused about one thing - If f is flat, all it does is that f[f[a,b],c] will be converted to f[a,b,c]; I guess it is intended to be used for pattern matching and working with associative products of formal variables. However, if f is a concrete function (rather than a formal associative product), then Flat doesn't instruct f[a,b,c] to be evaluated as f[f[a,b],c].

Comment: What precisely do you mean by a concrete function? For instance `SetAttributes[f,{Flat,OneIdentity}]; f[a_,b_]:=a+b; f[3,4,5]` does give `12`.

Comment: Oh I see, the issue seems deeper - This example above is fine, but mine is not, probably due to the fact that it is an operator on pure functions. Let's say the objects are infinite sequences `a[n]` (implemented as a pure function `a`) and we want to define the termwise sum `f[a,b]:=a[#1]+b[#1]&; SetAttributes[f,{Flat,OneIdentity}]`. Then `f[a,b][3]' gives `a[3]+b[3]` but `f[a,b,c][3]` just gives `f[a,b,c][3]` instead of the intended `a[3]+b[3]+c[3]`.

Comment: So `f[a_,b_]:=(a[#]+b[#]&); SetAttributes[f,{Flat,OneIdentity}]; f[a,b,c][3]` gives `a[3]+b[3]+c[3]`. You may have missed some underscores in the definition of `f`?

Comment: Oops I forgot to input the underscore here but I did in my original test...I find that `f[a_,b_]:=(a[#]+b[#]&)` works but `f[a_,b_]:=a[#]+b[#]&` doesn't - I am very confused now because this parenthesis is not supposed to make a difference, right?

Comment: After some retest, I find that the real problem seems to be that I need to set attributes before defining the function. The parenthesis doesn't matter. I need to run `f[a_,b_]:=(a[#]+b[#]&); SetAttributes[f,{Flat,OneIdentity}]` twice before it to work. Alternatively, if I do `SetAttributes[f,{Flat,OneIdentity}]; f[a_,b_]:=(a[#]+b[#]&)`, then once is enough.