# List of symbols without built-in meaning

Tags: formatting, built-in-symbols, custom-notation

Is there a list of all symbols with special display forms but no built-in meaning? That is, operators that are described in the tutorial [Operators without Built-in Meanings](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorsWithoutBuiltInMeanings.html)?

Comment: It is indeed nice to have the opportunity to define new notations with these symbols but isn't the fact that these symbols all come in the ````System` ```` context a [fundamental limitation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/214855/2249)?

Answer (score 27):

**Updated to include both unary and binary operators**

One idea is to use the usage message of a symbol as a clue that it has a special display form, probably with no built-in meaning. For example:

```
?TildeTilde
```

[image: tildetilde]

The following 2 functions check the usage message of a symbol to see if it contains "displays as" or "formats as", and then weeds out those symbols where the display boxes of the unary or binary operator indicates that it is a built-in symbol.

```
binaryQ[str_] := Module[
    {usage=ToExpression[str, InputForm, Function[x, MessageName[x, "usage"], HoldAll]]},

    If[!StringQ[usage]||StringFreeQ[usage,"displays as" | "formats as"], Return[False]];
    With[{sym=Symbol[str]},
        str =!= "EmbeddedHTML" &&
        FreeQ[
            MakeBoxes[sym[a,b]],
            PaneSelectorBox|TagBox|str|DynamicBox|PaneBox|PanelBox|InterpretationBox|DynamicWrapperBox
        ]
    ]
]

unaryQ[str_] := Module[
    {usage=ToExpression[str, InputForm, Function[x, MessageName[x, "usage"], HoldAll]]},

    If[!StringQ[usage]||StringFreeQ[usage,"displays as" | "formats as"],Return[False]];
    With[{sym=Symbol[str]},
        str=!="Defer" &&
        FreeQ[
            MakeBoxes[sym[a]],
            StyleBox|PaneSelectorBox|TagBox|str|DynamicBox|PaneBox|PanelBox
        ]
    ]
]
```

Here is the list of symbols created using the above predicate:

```
unaryOps = Cases[Names["*"], s_?unaryQ]
```

> {"AngleBracket", "BracketingBar", "CapitalDifferentialD", "CircleTimes",
>   "Coproduct", "Del", "DifferentialD", "DoubleBracketingBar", "MinusPlus",
>   "PlusMinus", "Square", "SubMinus", "SubPlus", "SubStar", "SuperDagger",
>   "SuperMinus", "SuperPlus", "SuperStar"}

```
binaryOps = Cases[Names["*"], s_?binaryQ]
```

> {"AngleBracket", "Backslash", "Because", "BracketingBar", "Cap", "CenterDot",
>   "CircleDot", "CircleMinus", "CirclePlus", "CircleTimes", "Colon",
>   "Congruent", "Coproduct", "Cup", "CupCap", "Diamond", "DotEqual",
>   "DoubleBracketingBar", "DoubleDownArrow", "DoubleLeftArrow",
>   "DoubleLeftRightArrow", "DoubleLeftTee", "DoubleLongLeftArrow",
>   "DoubleLongLeftRightArrow", "DoubleLongRightArrow", "DoubleRightArrow",
>   "DoubleRightTee", "DoubleUpArrow", "DoubleUpDownArrow", "DoubleVerticalBar",
>   "DownArrow", "DownArrowBar", "DownArrowUpArrow", "DownLeftRightVector",
>   "DownLeftTeeVector", "DownLeftVector", "DownLeftVectorBar",
>   "DownRightTeeVector", "DownRightVector", "DownRightVectorBar", "DownTee",
>   "DownTeeArrow", "EqualTilde", "Equilibrium", "GreaterEqualLess",
>   "GreaterFullEqual", "GreaterGreater", "GreaterLess", "GreaterTilde",
>   "HumpDownHump", "HumpEqual", "LeftArrow", "LeftArrowBar",
>   "LeftArrowRightArrow", "LeftDownTeeVector", "LeftDownVector",
>   "LeftDownVectorBar", "LeftRightArrow", "LeftRightVector", "LeftTee",
>   "LeftTeeArrow", "LeftTeeVector", "LeftTriangle", "LeftTriangleBar",
>   "LeftTriangleEqual", "LeftUpDownVector", "LeftUpTeeVector", "LeftUpVector",
>   "LeftUpVectorBar", "LeftVector", "LeftVectorBar", "LessEqualGreater",
>   "LessFullEqual", "LessGreater", "LessLess", "LessTilde", "LongLeftArrow",
>   "LongLeftRightArrow", "LongRightArrow", "LowerLeftArrow", "LowerRightArrow",
>   "MinusPlus", "NestedGreaterGreater", "NestedLessLess", "NotCongruent",
>   "NotCupCap", "NotDoubleVerticalBar", "NotEqualTilde", "NotExists",
>   "NotGreater", "NotGreaterEqual", "NotGreaterFullEqual", "NotGreaterGreater",
>   "NotGreaterLess", "NotGreaterSlantEqual", "NotGreaterTilde",
>   "NotHumpDownHump", "NotHumpEqual", "NotLeftTriangle", "NotLeftTriangleBar",
>   "NotLeftTriangleEqual", "NotLess", "NotLessEqual", "NotLessFullEqual",
>   "NotLessGreater", "NotLessLess", "NotLessSlantEqual", "NotLessTilde",
>   "NotNestedGreaterGreater", "NotNestedLessLess", "NotPrecedes",
>   "NotPrecedesEqual", "NotPrecedesSlantEqual", "NotPrecedesTilde",
>   "NotReverseElement", "NotRightTriangle", "NotRightTriangleBar",
>   "NotRightTriangleEqual", "NotSquareSubset", "NotSquareSubsetEqual",
>   "NotSquareSuperset", "NotSquareSupersetEqual", "NotSubset", "NotSubsetEqual",
>   "NotSucceeds", "NotSucceedsEqual", "NotSucceedsSlantEqual",
>   "NotSucceedsTilde", "NotSuperset", "NotSupersetEqual", "NotTilde",
>   "NotTildeEqual", "NotTildeFullEqual", "NotTildeTilde", "NotVerticalBar",
>   "Overscript", "PlusMinus", "Precedes", "PrecedesEqual", "PrecedesSlantEqual",
>   "PrecedesTilde", "Proportion", "Proportional", "ReverseElement",
>   "ReverseEquilibrium", "ReverseUpEquilibrium", "RightArrow", "RightArrowBar",
>   "RightArrowLeftArrow", "RightDownTeeVector", "RightDownVector",
>   "RightDownVectorBar", "RightTee", "RightTeeArrow", "RightTeeVector",
>   "RightTriangle", "RightTriangleBar", "RightTriangleEqual",
>   "RightUpDownVector", "RightUpTeeVector", "RightUpVector", "RightUpVectorBar",
>   "RightVector", "RightVectorBar", "ShortDownArrow", "ShortLeftArrow",
>   "ShortRightArrow", "ShortUpArrow", "SmallCircle", "SquareIntersection",
>   "SquareSubset", "SquareSubsetEqual", "SquareSuperset", "SquareSupersetEqual",
>   "SquareUnion", "Star", "Subscript", "Subset", "SubsetEqual", "Succeeds",
>   "SucceedsEqual", "SucceedsSlantEqual", "SucceedsTilde", "SuchThat",
>   "Superset", "SupersetEqual", "Therefore", "Tilde", "TildeEqual",
>   "TildeFullEqual", "TildeTilde", "Underscript", "UnionPlus", "UpArrow",
>   "UpArrowBar", "UpArrowDownArrow", "UpDownArrow", "UpEquilibrium",
>   "UpperLeftArrow", "UpperRightArrow", "UpTee", "UpTeeArrow", "Vee",
>   "VerticalBar", "VerticalSeparator", "VerticalTilde", "Wedge"}

And, here is a table showing the display forms of the symbols:

```
Replace[
    unaryOps,
    s_String :> Tooltip[Symbol[s][a], s],
    {1}
] //Multicolumn[#, 5, Dividers->All]&
```

[image]

```
Replace[
    binaryOps,
    s_String :> Tooltip[Symbol[s][a,b],s],
    {1}
] //Multicolumn[#,10,Dividers->All]&
```

[image]

As @Mr. Wizard shows in his answer, there are other undocumented symbols that have special formatting.

Comment: looks like a syntax error no first argument to `Function` and you use a slot symbol with no `&` ?

Comment: @george2079 It's not a syntax error, but it does look a bit odd. `Function[, f[#]]` is equivalent to `f[#]&`, you can use either `Function` or `&` but not both. I wanted to use the 3-arg version of `Function` to prevent an evaluation leak. Perhaps `Function[Null, MessageName[#, "usage"], HoldAll]` would have looked better.

Comment: oh I see. I thought it was not working but its just because processing all of `Names["*"]` takes a while.

Comment: @george2079 A related Q&A: [(29168)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29168/121)

Comment: Carl, is this list expected to be exhaustive?  Do all such operators have a usage message?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It would surprise me if there was such an operator without a usage message, but I won't claim my list is exhaustive without further research.

Comment: I found that your method is presently not exhaustive; please see my competing answer.

Answer (score 11):

Here is an approach based on reading the Front End resource `UnicodeCharacters.tr`.

This method finds some operators that do not presently appear in Carl Woll's list including documented operators [`CapitalDifferentialD`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CapitalDifferentialD.html), [`DifferentialD`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferentialD.html), and [`Square`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Square.html), and runs much more quickly.  However it also misses the bracketing operators i.e. `AngleBracket`, `BracketingBar`, `DoubleBracketingBar`.

```
ucharTR = ReadList[System`Dump`unicodeCharactersTR, Word, RecordLists -> True];

operators = 
  Cases[ucharTR, {_, ch_, ___, "Infix" | "Prefix" | "Postfix"(*|"InfixOpen"|"Open"|
      "Close"*), ___} :> StringTake[ch, {3, -2}]] /. "" -> Sequence[];

free =
  operators //
   Select[
    Module[{syms, msg},
      syms = 
       Rest @ Cases[MakeExpression["a\\[" <> # <> "\]b", StandardForm], 
         Except[HoldPattern[a | b | Times | Plus], _Symbol], {-1}, Heads -> True];
      msg = Quiet[MessageName[#, "usage"] & @@ syms];
      syms =!= {} && (! StringQ[msg] || StringContainsQ[msg, " displays as "])
    ] &
   ];
```

Extra operators my method finds:

```
Complement[free, undefined]
```

> ```
> {"CapitalDifferentialD", "DifferentialD", "ExpectationE", 
>  "InvisiblePostfixScriptBase", "InvisiblePrefixScriptBase", "Perpendicular",
>  "ProbabilityPr", "RoundImplies", "Square"}
> ```

Operators my method misses:

```
Complement[undefined, free]
```

> ```
> {"AngleBracket", "BracketingBar", "DoubleBracketingBar"}
> ```

Comment: "CapitalDifferentialD", "DifferentialD", "ExpectationE", "ProbabilityPR", "InvisiblePostfixScriptBase", "InvisiblePrefixScriptBase" and "Square" are all unary operators, and I purposely excluded them (I was interested in binary operators, even though I didn't specify that in my OP). "RoundImplies" seems to have a spurious `MakeBoxes` rule that disables formatting. "Perpendicular" does have a display form. Note that "ExpectationE", "ProbabilityPR", "RoundImplies", "InvisiblePostfixScriptBase", "InvisiblePrefixScriptBase" and "Perpendicular" are undocumented, so probably shouldn't use them.